# Getting and replacing specific words inside a document with jQuery or Javascript without lag or memory issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm making a google chrome extension that highlights a long list of specific words in the document. And when you hover over that word, it displays an iframe.
The thing is, since the list is pretty big (around 1500 words, the goal is to reach something like 10.000 or more), looping inside all the elements and trying to match those elements to any word is causing real lag in google chrome.
Here is what I have and IS WORKING as expected, but it causes the browser to freeze until it finishes the long loop.
Code (note that I'm seeing the index because sometimes that text contains multiple words to be highlighted):

$("*").contents().each(function () {

```
  if (this.nodeType == 3) { //if text
    if ($(this).text().trim() != '') {
      
          if ($(this).text().charAt(0).includes('.') || $(this).text().charAt(0).includes('{') || $(this).text().charAt(0).includes('@') || $(this).text().charAt(0).includes('!') || $(this).text().charAt(0).includes('(') || $(this).text().charAt(0).includes(' ') || $(this).text().charAt(0).includes(':') || $(this).text().charAt(0).includes('<') || $(this).text().includes('document.') || $(this).text().includes('html') || $(this).text().includes('var ') || $(this).text().charAt(0).includes(',') || $(this).text().charAt(0).includes('[') || $(this).text().charAt(0).includes('^') || $(this).text().charAt(0).includes('\n'))  {
            return
          } else {
            
            let checkIfTitle = $(this).parent()[0] as HTMLElement;
            if(!checkIfTitle?.outerHTML){
              return;
            }
            if(checkIfTitle.outerHTML.includes('<title')){
              return
            } else {

              checkGlobalWords = false;
              wordsHighlight.forEach((word) => {
                 if ($(this).text().includes(word.word)){
                   checkGlobalWords = true;
                   console.log($(this).text());
                 } else {
                   return;
                 }
              })
              
              if(checkGlobalWords){
                console.log($(this).text());
                wordsHighlight.forEach((word, index) => {
                  
                
                  let helperElement = $(this).parent()[0] as HTMLElement
                  
                  
                  if(helperElement.id === 'global-solution'){
                    return;
                  }
                  if(helperElement.tagName === 'TITLE'){
                    return;
                  }
                  if(helperElement.tagName === 'SCRIPT'){
                    return;
                  }
                  if(helperElement.tagName === 'STYLE'){
                    return;
                  }
                  if(index === 0){
                    textHelperMultipleWords = $(this).text();
                    if(textHelperMultipleWords.includes(word.word)){
                      textHelperMultipleWords = textHelperMultipleWords.replace(word.word, `<span id="global-solution" style="background-color: #ebf5f9; cursor: pointer; font-style: italic; text-transform: capitalize;">${word.word}</span>`)
                    }
                    return;
                  } 
                  if(index >= 1 && index < (wordsHighlight.length-1)){
                    if(textHelperMultipleWords.includes(word.word)){
                      textHelperMultipleWords = textHelperMultipleWords.replace(word.word, `<span id="global-solution" style="background-color: #ebf5f9; cursor: pointer; font-style: italic; text-transform: capitalize;">${word.word}</span>`)
                    }
                  }
              
                  
                  //console.log(index, wordsHighlight.length);
                  
                  if(index === (wordsHighlight.length-1)){
                    if(textHelperMultipleWords.includes(word.word)){
                      textHelperMultipleWords = textHelperMultipleWords.replace(word.word, `<span id="global-solution" style="background-color: #ebf5f9; cursor: pointer; font-style: italic; text-transform: capitalize;">${word.word}</span>`)
                    }
                    if(textHelperMultipleWords !== $(this).text()){
                      $(this).parent().html($(this).parent().html().replace($(this).text(), $(this).text().replace($(this).text(), textHelperMultipleWords)));
                    }
                    
                  }
                  
               
              })
              }
            }
          }
    }
  }
});
```

Any help here?

Thanks!

EDIT: I'm open to any solutions. Is there a way to run the code on an external server and then replace the entire document?

Answer (score 0):

There are some improvements that can be made to the code, such as

- Extracting values into variables instead of making function calls over and over again
- You can also use a much more concise regular expression for the starting characters blacklist, and an array of phrases to exclude.
- Another option is to check if the `helperElement` (the parent) is valid *before* iterating over the huge array, instead of checking if the parent is valid *for every single word in the array*.
- There's no need for the `checkGlobalWords` to iterate through every word first, then to iterate through every word again later when replacing - just replace unconditionally.
- Instead of doing an `.includes` test, and then replacing if that returns true, consider *unconditionally* replacing - saving you a step.
- Branches are, in general, slow. Instead of an if-else inside the big loop based on the index, perform the first test for only the first element of the array, then perform the second test for the rest of the elements of the array. Or, since it looks like they're doing nearly the same thing, except that the first initializes `textHelperMultipleWords` - just initialize that variable first, outside of the loop.
- Same thing for the final index - instead of checking if the index is the last, put that statement after the loop finishes.
- Since it looks like the only thing you care about in the big array is the `word` property of the objects, you can extract those words into their own array first to avoid having to navigate through the objects each time.
- The replacment of the text at the very end looks extraordinarily convoluted - why not just assign the new text to the element being iterated over?

```
const wordsToHighlight = wordsHighlight.map(obj => obj.word);
const badStartingCharacters = /[.{@!( :<^\n[]/;
const badPhrases = ['document.', 'html', 'var '];
$("*").contents().each(function () {
    if (this.nodeType !== 3) {
        return;
    }
    const text = $(this).text().trim();
    if (!text || badStartingCharacters.test(text[0]) || badPhrases.some(phrase => text.includes(phrase))) {
        return;
    }
    const parent = $(this).parent()[0] as HTMLElement;
    if (!parent?.outerHTML) {
        return;
    }
    if (parent.outerHTML.includes('<title')) {
        return;
    }
    if (parent.id === 'global-solution' || ['TITLE', 'SCRIPT', 'STYLE'].includes(parent.tagName)) {
        return;
    }
    let newText = text;
    wordsToHighlight.forEach((word) => {
        newText = newText.replace(word, `<span id="global-solution" style="background-color: #ebf5f9; cursor: pointer; font-style: italic; text-transform: capitalize;">${word}</span>`);
    });
    if (newText !== text) {
        $(this).text(newText);
    }
});
```

You can also probably make things a bit quicker by ditching jQuery - it isn't providing you any benefit here, and native DOM methods are faster.

All that said - if it's still too slow, this probably isn't something that's suited for the client-side. There are too many words for an average browser to handle. Yes, consider carrying out all of this logic on the server (only once, when the page changes), and then send the changed HTML to the client, instead of making clients do it every time they make a request.

Comment: Hi! your code seems REALLY good (and short), but it just don't stop loading (there is a bug somewhere making the loop infinite, i will have to review it). But i truly appreciate your detailed answer and i will update mine to see what i can do to improve with your advice.

Comment: I don't see the potential for any infinite loops in the code. Try cutting the `wordsHighlight` array down to a reasonable size, like 10 items, for testing.

Comment: i updated my question with the new code in pure JS that most part are yours. Thank you! working much better, still some ugly lag but just 1-2 seconds with a high amount of words (1500+ in pages with lots of nodes with nodeType 3)